# Yii2: Create a custom column to filter records based on a condition

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, kartik-v

I have a table of sales lines which include promo, service, and item columns among others. These 3 columns contain IDs from other tables. A sales line can only have a value for one of these fields e.g. if promo is not null, then the other 2 should be.

I have no problem with displaying the records since I have a description column that displays the corresponding description of any of the IDs. What I want to do is create a custom column to create a filter on the gridview that would select records that are for either service, promo, or item sales. Sor of like:

```
'filter' => ['Service' => 'service_id != null', 'Promo' => 'promo_id != null', 'Item' => 'item_id != null'],
```

I know the code above would not work but this is the general idea.

Thank you in advance!

I haven't tried anything yet since I don't really know where to start.

Comment: You can add custom property to your `Search` model, JavaScript (or Jquery) to filter your model on the new fields, in general: You can add any new properties and they can be displayed on the grid

Comment: I see. So just define a property, check that property's value, and then do a query depending on th value? Kinda like:

if($property == "service"){
    $query->andFilterWhere(['service' => !null]);
}

Comment: Yep, That shoud do the trick